# Why &x[0]+x.size() instead of &x[x.size()]?

Tags: c++, containers, stdvector

I'm reading A Tour of C++ (2nd edition) and I came across this code (6.2 Parameterized Types):

```
template<typename T>
T* end(Vector<T>& x)
{
     return x.size() ? &x[0]+x.size() : nullptr;     // pointer to one-past-last element 
}
```

I don't understand why we use `&x[0]+x.size()` instead of `&x[x.size()]`. Does it mean that we take the address of the first element in `x` and just add to that number `x.size()` bytes?

Comment: Nope, we don't add _'`x.size()` bytes'_ but rather `x.size()` times the size of each item. And the size of an item follows from the type of a pointer obtained by `&x[0]`. Seek the notion of 'pointer arithmetic' in C/C++.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`&x[x.size()]` would result in (attempting to) take the address of `x[x.size()]`. However `x[x.size()]` attempts to access an out of bound element; depending on the API of `Vector<T>::operator[]` for the particular `T`, a number of bad things could happen:

```
|    Vector<T>::operator[] semantics      |
| ======================================= |
| return\ contr |             |           |
| type   \ -act |  unchecked  |  checked  |
| --------------------------------------- |
| reference     |    UB (1)   |    FH     |
| value         |    UB (2)   |    FH     |
| --------------------------------------- |
```

with

- UB (1): undefined behavior when creating a reference to an out-of-range-element.
- UB (2): undefined behaviour when attempting to read the value of an out-of-range element.
- FH: some fault handling action from the API if it is checked (e.g. throwing an exception, terminating, ...).

For `std::vector`, as an example, you would run into UB (1) as its [`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) is unchecked and returns a reference type.

Whilst you may perform pointer arithmetics to compute a pointer to one-past-last (semantically `end()`) of a buffer, you may not dereference a one-past-last pointer.

Comment: That, or the `Vector<T>::operator[]` might actually check its input and throw or do something else.

Comment: @aschepler Good point, added into the answer.

Comment: @aschepler OK, got it. And what about `&x[x.size() - 1]`?

Comment: @adroit.levees.0r `&x[x.size() - 1]` is safe if `size() != 0`, but if would not give you a pointer to one-past-last (i.e. `end()`) but to last (i.e. `--end()`).

Comment: Taking the address of x[x.size()] does not access the element. It's that creating a reference to the element is already undefined behavior inside `std::vector::operator[]`, which does not bounds check as per standard.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Expanded with (ref, value) x (checked, unchecked) fault table.

Comment: What's FH? And I think (1) is not actually UB, since pointers (and refs?) to one-past-the-end array elements are allowed.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Pointer yes, Reference I believe not. A reference must "point" to a valid object or you have UB. That's why `a == nullptr` on a reference is always false per definition. Given a pointer `T *t = &x[size];` how you would return that: `return *t;`. It even looks like an access.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Apparently it's an [open issue](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#232), it's unclear if it's UB or not.

Comment: I can agree too that. I still believe it's UB because it would open the door to a whole lot of problems if it is not. A reference is supposed to be safer than a pointer and that would really make reference and pointer identical in their behavior. Anyway, the code in question simply side steps the problem by converting to pointer first and then going one past the end.